# javascript not accessing asp .net based html page element

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, textbox

I'm just trying to access the value of a textbox control (which has the runat="server" attribute). Been stuck for hours looking for an answer. Every time I try to get the value, it is null.

**The javascript file:**

```
function validateRegistration() {
var username = document.getElementById("<%=username.ClientId%>").value;
document.write(username);
}
```

**The aspx file:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <p>
        Fill in the following form to register:</p>
    <p>
        Username:
        <asp:TextBox ID="username" name="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
    <input id="register" type="submit" value="Register" onclick="validateRegistration()"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: 1. Are you that <%=username.ClientId%> appears in script file correctly? Checked it after page load?
2. The page will reload after submittin the form, you can add return false; in the end of JS function and change onclick="validateRegistration()" to onclick="return validateRegistration();"

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined. This is the error I get.

Comment: After page is loaded press Ctrl+U or use an inspector to check the JS script

Comment: I saw from the source code that the id without the .clientID function is mainContentPlaceHolder_username so I tried:                                                            var username = document.getElementById("mainContentPlaceHolder_username"); No luck! Didn't know this would be such a pain...

Comment: Try type document.getElementById("mainContentPlaceHolder_username") in Firebug/dev.tools console after page load. There are some issues with selector for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using

`var username = document.getElementById('<%= username.ClientID%>').value;`?

i have similar code in my page and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It should be (note the capital D):

```
var username = document.getElementById("<%=username.ClientID%>").value;
document.write(username);
```

Comment: I just tried that and same problem still. I don't think it makes a difference actually. Also the .value isn't even in the suggested codes list in the Visual Studio